# Upgrade Apache Solr 8.10.1 log4j 2.14.1 version to 2.15 to address critical vulnerability

Tags: java, solr, log4j

Recently a [critical log4j vulnerability](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) was discovered.

I want to upgrade the log4j as used by my current Solr instance, so I [checked here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/configuring-logging.html).
However, I don't see a `log4j.properties` file in "/server/resources/" folder.
All I see there is:

- jetty-logging.properties
- log4j2.xml
- log4j2-console.xml

None of these files contain a version. So to upgrade, is it safe to download the latest version of log4j and overwrite the existing jars in folder "\solr-8.10.1\server\lib\ext", or what are the recommended steps to upgrade?

Comment: the files containing the version should be in your directories server/lib/ext and contrib/prometheus-exporter/lib and these - all JARs - need to be replaced.

Comment: Official info is now available: 
https://solr.apache.org/security.html#apache-solr-affected-by-apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link you're pointing to is for an older version of Solr (6.6 instead of 8.10.1). The correct version is https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/configuring-logging.html where it mentions using log4j 2.

The file log4j2.xml (and even `log4j.properties for that matter) configure the logging itself, not the version of log4j. So updating that file is irrelevant.

Here's [what the project page recommends](https://solr.apache.org/security.html#apache-solr-affected-by-apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228):

> **2021-12-10, Apache Solr affected by Apache Log4J CVE-2021-44228**
>
> ...
>
> **Description:** Apache Solr releases prior to 8.11.1 were using a bundled version of the Apache Log4J library vulnerable to RCE. For full impact and additional detail consult the Log4J security page.
>
> ...
>
> **Mitigation:** Any of the following are enough to prevent this vulnerability for Solr servers:
>
> - Upgrade to Solr 8.11.1 or greater (when available), which will include an updated version of the log4j2 dependency.
> - Manually update the version of log4j2 on your runtime classpath and restart your Solr application.
> - (Linux/MacOS) Edit your solr.in.sh file to include: SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
> - (Windows) Edit your solr.in.cmd file to include: set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
> - Follow any of the other mitgations listed at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html

What you're proposing (overwrite the existing jars in folder "\solr-8.10.1\server\lib\ext") seems like the second approach, so it should probably work fine. Just make sure this is the correct place that contains the log4j dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the old jars and replaced with newer ones. Is there a way to validate everything is safe now?

Comment: @Adam As long as no old jar is present in your installation and only the 2.15 new version, it should be fine. [This tool](https://github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector) can also help, but haven't tried it.

Comment: @Adam you can put a TCP listener (e.g. ncat) on a specific port and submit a query with the offending string to validate that Solr is not making the connection as it logs. https://hectorcorrea.com/blog/log4shell-and-solr/88

Comment: Followed the instructions here. But after restart I keep getting ```SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.```. Any suggestions on what else I can do to fix it?

Comment: Ok solved it by adding slf4j-simple-*.jar as well in the classpath

Answer (score 4):

Replace all the jars with their corresponding 2.15 version in lib/ext and restart solr. Seem to work.

1. log4j-api-2.11.0.jar
2. log4j-core-2.11.0.jar
3. log4j-1.2-api-2.11.0.jar
4. log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.0.jar

Comment: did you just replace them without renaming the file or did you rename all 2.15 to 2.11?

Comment: From where you get all the specific jars?

Comment: @user557657 see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Comment: Will it effect any dependency with solr?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answers. It saves my time !!

Answer (score 2):

I updated all of my log4j jars from 2.11 to 2.15 in my /opt/solr-7.4.0/server/lib/ext folder and I am not seeing any issues. Your approach seems to work.

Comment: did you just replace them without renaming the file or did you rename all 2.15 to 2.11?

Comment: I deleted all files with the suffix of 2.11 and added files with suffix 2.15. I did not rename any files. I just added and deleted.

Answer (score 2):

With [the new CVE](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105) `SOLR_OPTS` is not enough. Upgrading to 2.17 seems like the best option. Here's what worked for us.

```
sudo find / -name "*log4j*"
cd /app/solr/solr-7.7.0/server/lib/ext/
sudo curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.17.0/apache-log4j-2.17.0-bin.zip --output apache-log4j-2.17.0-bin.zip
sudo unzip apache-log4j-2.17.0-bin.zip
sudo rm log4j-*-2.11*
sudo cp apache-log4j-2.17.0-bin/{log4j-1.2-api-2.17.0.jar,log4j-api-2.17.0.jar,log4j-core-2.17.0.jar,log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.0.jar} ./
sudo chown solr:solrgrp *
sudo chmod 755 *
sudo service solr restart

cd /app/solr/solr-7.7.0/contrib/prometheus-exporter/lib/
sudo rm log4j-*-2.11*
sudo cp /app/solr/solr-7.7.0/server/lib/ext/apache-log4j-2.17.0-bin/{log4j-api-2.17.0.jar,log4j-core-2.17.0.jar,log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.0.jar} ./
sudo chown solr:solrgrp *
sudo chmod 755 *
sudo service solr restart
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Solr version 8.6.4 I did now an update to log4j2 2.16 by simply exchanging the 5 log4j*.jar files under "Solr\server\lib\ext". In addition I also had to update slf4j-api.jar to version 1.7.24. This seems to work out of the box.

download links:

- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.9/

-> [updated lib files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbsRC.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Mitigation: Any of the following are enough to prevent this vulnerability for Solr servers:**

- Upgrade to Solr 8.11.1 or greater (when available), which will
  include an updated version (>= 2.17.0) of the Log4J dependency.
- If
  you are using Solr's official docker image, it has already been
  mitigated in all versions listed as supported on Docker Hub:
  https://hub.docker.com/_/solr. You may need to re-pull the image.
- Manually update the version of Log4J on your runtime classpath and
  restart your Solr application.
- (Linux/MacOS) Edit your solr.in.sh
  file to include: SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS
  -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
- (Windows) Edit your solr.in.cmd file to include: set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS%
  -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
- Follow any of the other mitgations listed at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html

Refering to: https://solr.apache.org/security.html#apache-solr-affected-by-apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228

In my case the following jars were affected and replaced by the latest package directly from [Apache](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/logging/log4j/2.17.0/apache-log4j-2.17.0-bin.zip). Use something like the [log4j detector](https://github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector) to identify affected jars.

- %SOLRINST%\solr\contrib\prometheus-exporter\lib\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\contrib\prometheus-exporter\lib\log4j-core-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\contrib\prometheus-exporter\lib\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\server\lib\ext\log4j-1.2-api-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\server\lib\ext\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\server\lib\ext\log4j-core-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\server\lib\ext\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar
- %SOLRINST%\solr\server\lib\ext\log4j-web-2.11.2.jar

Comment: Watch out! Although the `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"` will mitigate the specific vulnerability, there are still other attacks possible ( https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/12/log4j-zero-day-vulnerability/ ). You should upgrade Log4j to at least 2.17.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Solr as a docker, what you can do is mount the same log4j-core version that uses in Solr image, outside after removing `JndiLookup.class` from the jar.

Let me go through the steps that I have used.

- Find the log4j-core version that Solr image is using. You can do it by executing following command in your Solr running host machine or after go inside your Solr container

  find / -name "log4j-core-*.jar"
- There you will get two paths. According to [Solr security news page](https://solr.apache.org/security.html#apache-solr-affected-by-apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228), we can neglect the `prometheus-exporter` path. What will remain is `server/lib/ext/` path
- Copy that particular .jar file or download the same version from the Internet. I have tested this with `log4j-core-2.11.2.jar`
- Copy that jar file in to your Solr container running host machine and check it's vulnerability status using this [log4j-detector](https://github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector).
- It's nothing complicated, to check that vulnerability using above mentioned tool. What you need to do is download that `log4j-detector-2021.12.16.jar` file to an accessible location and run the command against your log4j-core jar file.

  java -jar log4j-detector-2021.12.16.jar 8.4.1-ext > hits_8.4.1_ext.txt

Then you will get an output like below by saying it is vulnerable.

> /ext/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar contains Log4J-2.x   >= 2.10.0 *VULNERABLE*
> :-(

- Now let's remove the `JndiLookup.class` from that log4j-core jar file

  zip -q -d 8.4.1-ext/ext/log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
- Then, check the vulnerability again against the same log4j-core jar file and you will be able to see something like below.

> /ext/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar contains Log4J-2.x   <= 2.0-beta8
> *POTENTIALLY_SAFE* :-| (or did you already remove JndiLookup.class?)

That means JndiLookup.class removal has done successfully.

- Let's mount that log4j-core jar file using using docker-compose.yaml

  volumes:

  - ./log4j-core-2.11.2.jar:/opt/solr-8.4.1/server/lib/ext/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar
- Now, restart your Solr docker container.

---

My personal preference is updating property with `SOLR_OPTS` with environment variables, since it is nice and clean.