# Apache Solr 5.4 version Log4j upgrade from 1.x to 2.18.0 version

Tags: java, solr, log4j

I need to upgrade log4j 1.x to log4j 2.18.0 in my project which is using Apache Solr 5.4.0 which is internally using log4j 1.2.17 and other slf4j dependencies, when I am excluding it from pom it is giving exception of accessing Level class internally, therefore, the exclusion will not work it seems, I tried exploring and found this [Upgrade Apache Solr 8.10.1 log4j 2.14.1 version to 2.15 to address critical vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70337252/upgrade-apache-solr-8-10-1-log4j-2-14-1-version-to-2-15-to-address-critical-vuln)
but it seems this is for solr 8.1 or later which already using log4j2, so please help me in getting log4j upgrade in my project which is using solr 5.4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why you not upgrade to solr 8. Looks like the version 5 is 8 years old?

Comment: its the project need and need approval from senior management, for that I need to give them the valid reason that its impossible to upgrade log4j in solr 5.4 @Jens

Comment: read https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html there you should find the solution at *log4j-over-slf4j* But I would suggest also upgrade solr

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done cleanly. You likely cannot just switch to a new major version without being able to change the code, depending on how solr utilizes logging. You can of course create an dummy jar file that imitates the required log4j1.x classes